# event solver ivp python

Tags: python, scipy, game-physics

I am looking for a solution to a collision event using the ivp_solver in python. I want there to be a 2 pendulum swinging and colliding then bouncing. How can i use the ivp_solver's 'event' option when I'm passing the position of another pendulum? To clarify, here is my code..

Variables,

```
t_span = [0, 150]
y0_pend = [0, 3]
t = np.linspace(t_span[0], t_span[1], 10000)
p = [2, 3]
b = 0
n = np.linspace(1, 1000, 1000)
```

These are the functions,

```
def pend1_f(t, y):
    k = 1
    d = 0.1

    dx = k * y[1]
    dv = -y[0] - d * dx

    return [dx, dv]
```

```
def pend2_f(x, p, b):
    return [b + np.cos(p * x), -p * np.sin(p*x)]
```

Solving the ODE,

```
zt = solve_ivp(pend_f, t_span, y0_pend, dense_output = True)
z = zt.sol(t)
pendulum_position = z[0]
pendulum_velocity = z[1]
```

So if i want to check where the 2 periodic curves intersect and then collide and then change the velocity so that i can simulate a bounce, how can I do that? I am aware there is an 'event' option in the solve_ivp parameters so i'm guessing i can do something with that. Any help would be appreciated <3

`# np.argwhere(np.diff(np.sign(list1 - list2))).flatten()`

I found this but all this does is find the intersections between the 2 curves, i need to be able to interrupt the solver, change the velocity parameter and continue solving from the point of collision.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The best way to do this is to use an event function. The event function will take in the current time, position, and velocity of each pendulum and decide if a collision has occurred. It will then return a boolean value indicating if a collision has occurred.

```
def collision_event(t, y, v):
x1, x2, v1, v2 = y[0], y[1], v[0], v[1]
if np.abs(x1 - x2) < 0.1:
    # Calculate new velocities
    v1 = -v1
    v2 = -v2
    return True, [v1, v2]
else:
    return False, None
```

If a collision has occurred, you can use the current time, position, and velocity to calculate the new velocity for each pendulum after the collision. You can then pass this new velocity back to the solver as the initial condition, and the solver will continue from the point of collision.

For example, here is a simple event function that you can use:

Then you can pass this event to the solver using the 'events

Comment: *"here is a simple event function that you can use"* Where?